# Can't get x coord trafo to use previously used x values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I would like to replicate an Arrhenius plot: it's a semi-log plot presenting something as a function of 1000/*T* (*T* being the temperature in Kelvin). This is not very convenient for the reader, so an additional axis with *T* is required.

I have tried using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534118/pgfplots-second-axis-with-different-scaling-x-coord-trafo) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449337/pgfplots-2nd-y-axis-without-data) as well but I always end up with the secondary axis ranging from 0 to 1 instead of ~380 to 710. My guess is I haven't written properly the `x coord trafo` line.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*= bottom,
        axis y line*= left,
        ymode = log,
        xlabel={1000/T (1/K)},
        ylabel = phi,
        xmin = 1.4,
        xmax = 2.6,
        ymin = 3e-14,
        ymax = 5e-11
    ]
        \addplot[red] {9.39e-9*exp(-37.3e3/(8.314*(1000/x)))};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*= top,
        axis y line*= right,
        xlabel={T (K)},
        xmin=2.6,
        xmax=1.4,
        xtick={500, 600},
        ytick=\empty,
        x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{1000/#1}
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the very unsatisfying result

[image: Top x axis ranges from 0 to 1 instead of actual temperatures around 500K]

Bonus points if you can make the right-hand side ticks go away or at least correspond to the left-hand ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to make use of the feature that expressions can be given to `xticklabel`.

For details have a look at the comments in the code. (Please note that I also did some other "improvements" to your code which might be useful.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % (use this `compat` level or higher to make use of the improved axis label positioning)
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % (so we don't have to repeat ourselves we define some variables)
    /pgf/declare function={
        xmin=1.4;
        xmax=2.6;
    },
    % (moved stuff here which is used in both `axis` environments)
    every axis/.append style={
        xmin=xmin,
        xmax=xmax,
        % (restrict `domain` to the used region ...
        domain=xmin:xmax,
        %  ... and since it is a straight line we only need two `samples`)
        samples=2,
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        ymode=log,
        % (just improved the `axis` labels a bit)
        xlabel={$1000/T$ (1/K)},
        ylabel=$\varphi$,
        ymin=3e-14,
        ymax=5e-11,
    ]
        \addplot [red] {9.39e-9*exp(-37.3e3/(8.314*(1000/x)))};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*=top,
        axis y line*=right,
        xlabel={$T$ (K)},
        % show the "usual" x-axis
        xticklabel={
            \pgfmathparse{1000/\tick}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        ytick=\empty,
    ]
        % we need to add a dummy point to plot the right axis labels
        \addplot [draw=none,fill=none] coordinates {(2,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Works like a charm !
Can I still pick which ticks appear on the top axis with xticks={} ?

Comment: Great to hear. I think you mean `xtick`, right? (`xticks` shouldn't exist.) I don't see why not. (Did you give it a try before asking?)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it is indeed ```xtick={}```.


I tried it, by simply adding ```xtick={600, 500, 400},``` right before ```ytick={}```

It makes the top ticks vanish and throws error "dimension too large". 
Changing the order of the ticks to ```xtick={400, 500, 600},``` gives the same error.

Comment: That's because you need to provide the "1000/T" values, i.e. `xtick={1000/400,1000/500,1000/600},`.

Comment: Indeed ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.